# When I convert python object column to string, observations disappear

Tags: python, pandas, string, object, encoding

I want to convert a pandas column of object type to string becasue that's how I can merge with other column properly, but after converting, the number of observations drops. Several vales disappear. How can I solve it?

Initially, I have 3300 unique observations in the column.

I use:

```
df["article"]= df["article"].astype('string')
```

Now I have only 3000 unique observations.

I have also tried:

```
df["article"]= df["article"].astype('str')
df["article"]= str(df["article"])
```

but it's just worse, I got even less observations.

I have tried

```
str.strip()
str.encode("utf-8")
```

to check them, but the problem is still there.

You u have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you checked and compared the input and output series to see which rows were dropped in the process? That might give you some information about what's happening

Comment: Please read [mre]. Can you reproduce the problem using only the first half of the dataset? (If not, how about only the second half?) If you repeat this process, can you create a small dataset (just a few rows) that exhibits the problem? Please try to do this, and then *show us* data that we can use to reproduce the problem. Better yet, give code that creates such a dataset, so that there is no ambiguity about data types etc.

Comment: Hey, I managed to figure out the problem. The data was from an excel file, and some cells were formatted as stirng while others as number. Because the differences in formatting, using openpyxl, pandas detected more unique values than actually was there. I corrected it in excel first, and now when I convert the column to string I have the same number of unique values.